# Adding Modal on View button in Table

Tags: reactjs, use-state, simplemodal

I want to add a modal on the view button on my table,
When I clicked the view button, I want only the full name and the Department to be seen as Modal

How do I add modal on this table and select specific data

Here is my source code

https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-shadow-xvolj

Comment: simple, create a modal component, when a view button is clicked: 

 1. update a state with the data you want to show in modal,
 2.  view the modal (toggle state)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new state hook

```
const [modelState, setModelState] = useState({
    showModel: false,
    data: null
 })
```

Also update the state on click on view

```
onClick={() =>
   setModelState({ showModel: true, data: row })
}
```

And design your model component declaring it in JSX

```
 {modelState.showModel && (
    <div>Model here {console.log(modelState.data)}</div>
  )}
```

Fixed source code: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-edison-bughp

Comment: I put {modelState.data} instead of {console.log(modelState.data)}  , all of the content is missing

Comment: No you  cannot print a object directly in JSX. Print it like {modelState.data.id} or Iterate modelState.data.cells and print it . So you have a whole object you just need to print it in the way u want in model